# React js firebase fcm token not getting genrated when notifcation is not allowed in browser

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to genarete a fcm token in react js it is working when i  manally allow notification in google crome the token gets genrated but it doesnot work when i use
incoginto mode where the notification pernistion is not alloved how can i solve this?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getFcmToken = async () => {
      const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
      if (permission === "granted") {
        const token = await getToken(messaging, {
          vapidKey:
            "BInjEWhqUD-JZMVN1ClioA8GrKKfcJtg-OQFOigst3agDUVw0LGqxkYu55dir95S4sv8kXZgwpvXqZ9_ZfzfVbM",
        });
        setFcmToken(token);
        console.log("Token Gen", token);
        // Send this token  to server ( db)
      } else if (permission === "denied") {
        console.log(permission);
      }
    };

    getFcmToken();
  }, []);
```

is there any method to genarete the token if the notfication is not allowed?